# Backbone.history.navigate not working

Tags: backbone.js, router

My app init looks as follows:

```
    var $ = jQuery = require('jquery'),
    Router = require('./router'),
    Backbone = require('backbone');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');

var app = {
    init: function () {
        "use strict";
        Backbone.$ = $;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            this.router = new Router();
            console.log("In router");
            /*if (!Backbone.history.start()) {
                router.navigate('404', {trigger:true});
            }*/
            Backbone.history.start();
        });

        // All navigation that is relative should be passed through the navigate
        // method, to be processed by the router.  If the link has a data-bypass
        // attribute, bypass the delegation completely.
        $(document).on("click", "a:not([data-bypass])", function (evt) {
            // Get the anchor href and protcol
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            var protocol = this.protocol + "//";

            // Ensure the protocol is not part of URL, meaning its relative.
            if (href && href.slice(0, protocol.length) !== protocol &&
                href.indexOf("javascript:") !== 0) {
                // Stop the default event to ensure the link will not cause a page
                // refresh.
                evt.preventDefault();

                // `Backbone.history.navigate` is sufficient for all Routers and will
                // trigger the correct events.  The Router's internal `navigate` method
                // calls this anyways.
                Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
            }
        });
    }
};

app.init();
```

My routes:

```
    var $ = jQuery = require('jquery'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    loginView = require('./views/login/LoginView'),
    userActivitiesMainView = require('./views/dashboard/UserActivitiesMainView'),
    mainDashboardView = require('./views/dashboard/MainDashboardView');

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.currentView = null;
    },
    setCurrentView: function (view) {
        if (this.currentView &&
            typeof this.currentView.onClose != 'undefined') {
            this.currentView.onClose();
        }

        this.currentView = view;
        $('body').scrollTop(0);

    },
    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "login(/)": "home",
        "dashboard(/)": "dashboard",
    },
    notFound: function () {
        this.setCurrentView(null);
        $('.div-main').html('<h2>Oops! Page not found. Please try going back from the browser.</h2>');
    },
    dashboard: function () {
        "use strict";
        var dashboard = new mainDashboardView();
        this.setCurrentView(dashboard);
        this.addSideBar();
        this.addHeaderBar();
    },
    home: function () {
        "use strict";
        var login = new loginView();
        this.setCurrentView(login);
    },
    addSideBar: function () {
        var sidebar = new sidebarView();
        //this.setCurrentView(sidebar);
    },
    //Function to add header
    addHeaderBar: function () {
        var header = new headerView();
        //this.setCurrentView(header);
    }

})
module.exports = Router;


     var ret = Backbone.history.navigate('dashboard', true);
        console.log(ret); // comes false for me
```

**I have tried everything it doesn't work**

Edit:

I am calling the navigate in the View as follows:

```
   events: function () {
    return this.appendEvents({
        'click #btnContinue': 'login'
    })
},
login: function () {
    var otp = this.$el.find('#otp').val();
    var data = {
        "mobile_number": sessionStorage.getItem('mobile_number'),
        "otp": otp,
        "name_of_user": "Vini",
        "flag": "payment_link",
        "title": "Pen and Pencil and rose",
        "description": "You can write and erase and smile and pay",
        "amount": "50.00",
        "images": [
            "ac19fa94-9f5f-48e0-93a7-53d5da616ac3",
            "13da680e-6050-40e0-97c8-cc141d1439d9"
        ]
    };
    this.loginModel.set(data);
    this.loginModel.save().then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        Cookies.set('API', response);
        var ret = Backbone.history.navigate('#dashboard', { trigger: true});
        console.log(ret);
    })
}
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior? what's really happening instead? What's the exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from calling `navigate` before calling `Backbone.history.start()`.

You call `Backbone.history.navigate('dashboard', true)` immediately after defining your router, but only call `Backbone.history.start()` on document `ready`.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        this.router = new Router();

        Backbone.history.start();

        // Initial navigate can be done here
        Backbone.history.navigate('dashboard', true);
        // or
        this.router.navigate('dashboard', true);
    });
```

Also, if you want to navigate on a link click, you can use the `href` property as any other link tag.

```
<a href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

If you're using fragment routes like the following, don't forget to call `navigate` with a `#/` in front of the route you want.

```
http://example.com/page/#/fragment/route/here
```

Comment: I am calling the navigate on click why would i want to do in document.ready function?

Comment: @vini The problem isn't defined clearly in your question, it's just a big code snippet... I was referring to the last line of your `Router`.